# Design for dealing with configuration files

Tags: python, json, configuration

I'm writing code that needs to open a JSON file which contains general configurations related to the use of the software, parse it to a dict and possibly overwrite some of its values. These configurations need to be accessed several times during runtime to check settings.

For exemple: one of the configurations is 'username' and 'password', which need to be filled by the user if it doesn't exist, or just read otherwise. Another config is related to "how the software should work", having possible values of "mode A", "mode B" and "mode C".

**Problem is:** I'm not a programmer, and I can't figure out a good design to manage configs. Should I open the JSON file, rewrite and save it everytime that I need, or parse it to a variable and keep this variable in memory until the moment I don't need it anymore (just before code finishes running), then save it to the JSON file at the end?

**Another question is:** in case I prefer to parse it to a variable and keep it until program ends, how should I do it? This variable would need to be accessed by several functions, so I thought I should use a global variable, but I've read that using the "global" statement to write to globals is a bad practice and can lead to a mess. Example:

```
import json
config_global = None

def read_JSON_file():
    config_file = open(r'config_file.json')
    global config_global
    config_global = json.load(config_file)
    config_file.close()

def functionA():
    global config_global
    # Do something with config_global

def functionB():
    global config_global
    # Do something with config_global

def save_JSON_file()
    config_file = open(r'config_file.json', 'w')
    json.dump(config_global, config_file)
    config_file.close()

read_JSON_file()
functionA()
functionB()
save_JSON_file()
```

---

I also thought that I could pass the config variable reference between function calls, but I don't know if it would be a good solution, since I would have to pass it for EVERY function, EVERYTIME:

```
import json

def read_JSON_file() -> dict:
    config_file = open(r'config_file.json')
    config = json.load(config_file)
    config_file.close()
    return config

def functionA(config: dict):
    # Do something with config

def functionB(config: dict):
    # Do something with config

def save_JSON_file(config: dict)
    config_file = open(r'config_file.json', 'w')
    json.dump(config, config_file)
    config_file.close()

parsed_config = read_JSON_file()
functionA(parsed_config)
functionB(parsed_config)
save_JSON_file(parsed_config)
```

---

I've also read something related to the use of a singleton, which I don't fully understand how it would work, or if it would be a good solution.

Ultimately, I'd like to know what would be a good solution for this. Please show me the possible problems I could face with my implementations, and fell free to suggest better solutions.

Thank you for your attention and help.

Comment: I'm a programmer and I can't figure out a good design for managing configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the configuration a module, which can be `import`ed in whole or part in any other script that needs it. Modules are essentially singletons and are cached in `sys.modules` when they are first loaded and that entry will be used if there are subsequent attempts to re-`import` it—so it doesn't incur the overhead of actually being read and executed everytime that occurs.

In the main body of the configuration module, you can open and load the information in the json file. This info could be made available in many ways. One would be to a simple dictionary (possibly just whatever `json.load()` returns. Another would be parse and transform it and create module attributes corresponding the various portions of it.

Of course you can also add whatever functions you wish to the module. For example you might want a special function that must be called before the values it contains are available—instead of doing it automatically when it's first imported.

In other words, it's would be a very flexible way to handle the problem and allow lots of customization since it's extensible.

Comment: OK, so I would have a new module, which contains a global variable called "config_global", that would have the value of the dict returned by json.load(), right? Then, when I need to access the configurations, I would import this new module and get it "config_global" variable. But if I need to overwrite configurations in config_global variable, wouldn't I be writing to a global anyways (even if it is inside other module)?

Comment: You could `from config import config_global` assuming you name the module `config.py` and it defines a module-level variable named `config_global` (which was populated by reading the json file). If you change the contents of  `config_global` they will remain in memory and be seen by any other scripts that have (or will) also `import` it. You can add a function to the module that will write the current contents either back to the original file or another—all depends on what and how you would using it to work because you're able to define the API for working with it as you see fit.

Comment: OK, I got it, and it seems like a good solution, but I still have a question: in the "config.py" module, "config_global" is a global (module level) variable. So, if I write to it when I first populate it reading the json file or when I change some configuration during runtime, I would essentially be writing to a global. Wouldn't it still be considered a bad practice (because writing to a global is usually considered a bad practice)?

Comment: It's a module-level global, which is slightly different (and less onerous) than what are usual called global variables in other languages. If you're worried about even using on in an external module, you can provide functions to get and set values in it instead of directly making changes to it in scripts that `import` it. Think of your `config.py` module as defining a single instance of module object (which in fact is what goes on). Like any class, you can provide "getters" and "setters" to control access to the instance's internals (or not). In Python, it's common **not** to provide them.